# Typo3 inherit data when if is true

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I generate an lib.content with the current content but i want to add it only if the following if statement will be true, otherwise not/empty:

```
lib.content = COA
lib.content{
    10 < styles.content.get
    10.stdWrap.cObject.if{
        value.data = DB:pages:{page:uid}:nav_hide
        value.data.insertData = 1
        equals = 1
    }
}
```

is this possible or where's the error in the syntax?

Version of Typo3 is 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "insertData" twice, because it replaces `{page:uid}` with the UID (e.g. `5`), but it keeps the rest `DB:pages:5:nav_hide`.

The rest `DB:pages:5:nav_hide` needs to be "data inserted" again, so the trick is to use `wrap3`.

Solution:

```
lib.content = COA
lib.content {
    10 < styles.content.get
    10.stdWrap.cObject.if {
        // Replaces page:uid
        value.dataWrap = DB:pages:{page:uid}:nav_hide
        // Wraps curly brackets around DB:pages:5:nav_hide
        value.wrap3 = {|}
        // Replaces DB:pages:5:nav_hide with the nav_hide value
        value.insertData = 1
        equals = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: made my day! perfect and good explained